# Explanation to the output

Tags: c++, dev-c++

Why does the program output 5 lightning strikes, and not 1,2,3 lightning strikes consecutively?

```
int main()
{

    int flashes[5] = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5};
    int x;
    for (x = 0; x < 4; x++);
    {
       cout<<flashes[x]<<" Lightning Strike"<<endl;
    }   
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Note the `;` after for `for (...)`, it's interpreted as an empty loop body. Everything that follows isn't a part of the loop body.

Comment: crank up your warning level and pay attention to them, `-Wall` for gcc tells you what is wrong

Comment: Something that would have also caught this is declaring `x` in the loop like you're supposed to.

Comment: this and similar typos is what makes me believe puttin the bracket on the same line is less error-prone, though majority uses different convention

Answer (score 2):

The line

```
    for (x = 0; x < 4; x++);
```

is an "empty controlled statement", you should write

```
  for (x = 0; x < 4; x++)
```

(without semi-colon).

Comment: ok thank you for that, but when I tested to cout the value of x below the lightning strike statement , the x value turns out to be 4, why is that so?

Comment: Well, try `x <= 4` or `x < 5` then.

Comment: `x < 5` will be more common in `c++`